# Asyncio.sleep() после, например, 10 или 50 запросов aiohttp в asyncio.gather()

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Нужна возможность делать таймауты после определенного количества запросов в asyncio.gather()
Пытался обойтись таким решением -

```
async def delay_wrapper(delay, task):
    print(f'Resp with delay {delay}')
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return await task


async def async_prepare(source: str):
    while True:
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
                    connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, verify_ssl=False)) as session:
                async with session.get(source, headers=HEADEARS) as response:
                    response_result = await response.read()
                    return response_result
        except aiohttp.ClientConnectionError:
            print("Oops - ClientConnectionError - the connection was dropped before we finished")

await asyncio.gather(*[delay_wrapper(delay, async_prepare(source=url)) for url in self.urls], return_exceptions=True)
```

Но в итоге сначала отрабабывает sleep, а уже после них скопом идут выполняться запросы... А мне нужна поочердность... А еще лучше. чтобы sleep() выполнялся после некоторого количества запросов, например после 30 или 50...
Понимаю, что в лоб это можно реализовать разбив self.urls на чанки и отправлять в .gather() по частям со sleep() после каждой порции. Но хотелось бы более элегантное решение...

Comment: Зачем вы делаете sleep? Пытаетесь обойти лимит на количестов запросов в секунду?

Comment: Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA
 Ну конечно! Только ради этого... Но пока не понятно какое количество запросов в секунду блочит конечный сервис по данному айпишнику(((

Comment: Тогда вам, возможно, поможет ответ на этот вопрос ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1421039/218971

Comment: Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA
Спасибо большое, Вам, но оччч запутанно... Было бы круто, если бы был флаг, который можно бы было установить в функции, которая запускает запросы по какому-то параметру - по времени или по частоте запросов. И главное, чтобы этот флаг не обнулялся другими запушенными тасками, а позволял засыпать скрипт и не делать запросов...

Answer (score 0):

Ограничение на количество одновременных запросов, полезно в этом плане:

```
para_sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10) 
async def delay_wrapper(delay, task):
    async with para_sem:
        return await task
```

Вроде бы не то что нужно автору, но отпускать семафор вручную... Покажу на простом примере, чтоб не путать.

```
RATE = 50
rate_sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(10)
async def delay_wrapper(delay, task):
    await rate_sem.acquire()
    return await task

async def releaser():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1/RATE)
        try:
            rate_sem.release() 
        except ValueError:
            pass 

rt = asyncio.create_task(releaser())
await asyncio.gather(*[delay_wrapper(delay, async_prepare(source=url)) for url in self.urls], return_exceptions=True)
rt.cancel()
```

Запускается одновременно 10 запросов и каждые 1/50 секунды разрешается ещё один.

П.С. тут теряется обратная связь на окончание запросов. Нужно совместить 2 семафора получить 2 эффекта.

А по "флагам" посмотри другие примитивы из раздела https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Можно подумать реализацию на очереди и воркерах.

Comment: eri, Вы про rabbit, сеlery или kafka? А чем мне тут могут помочь очереди и воркеры? Мне всё равно придётся как продумывать таймаут. Но возможно там, конечно, это будет сделать проще!

Comment: я про синхронизацию внутри процесса. вешать кролика для парсинга это оверхед. а в очереди можно контролировать скорость наполнения.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что имеете ввиду? collections.deque() и/или queue.Queue()?

Comment: Есть ещё asyncio.Queue)